# K - Map essential and non-essential prime implicants

Tags: digital-logic

Here is the min terms for K - map simplification:

```
F = summetion m(0,2,3,5,7,8,10,11,14,15)
```

May i know, if i draw the graph means, what will i get Essential and Non Essential prime implicants?

Can anyone help me?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]note 1's with dots are Essential  prime implicants

Comment: still i didn't get exact solution.. In my question have only 3 essential .. but i don't know ..how.? help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Essential and Non Essential prime implicants is nothing but a necessary grouping and unnecessary grouping in general words for example[image]

Comment: i think , you mess 3, i mean 0011..

Comment: its a example ,which leads to your answer

Comment: can you please provide me answer for my question? thanks

Comment: may i know, why these are essential prime implicants? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule of thump to find essential and non-essential prime implicants:

- Keep on trying to combine maximum number of squares in the k-map (like you normally do for reduction of the given min terms).
- Uh oh, you are suddenly confused which square a particular minterm should be a part of. Eg: in the example, you get the same kind of confusion while trying to include the minterm "3" (should I go for [3, 2, 11, 10] or [3, 7, 11, 15]?)
- While finding largest possible combinations of minterms, if there is at least one minterm in a combination that is never confusing regarding which combination it should be a part of, that combination is essential (eg: No confusion regarding 0: it MUST be in the combination [0, 2, 8, 10]. There simply aren't any other 4-term combinations that could include 0. So, this combination is essential).